# How to save all titles in HandbrakeCLI?

Tags: handbrake

So I'm trying to copy an old DVD with HandbrakeCLI, and because it takes forever to do so, I would like to know if I'm doing it the correct way.

The DVD has four (4) episodes, the episodes may have chapters.

I would like to grab all episodes so that they are in mkv format.

I tried this `for i in 'seq 4'; do HandBrakeCLI --input /dev/dvd --title $i --preset Normal -e x264 -q 20 -w 1280 -l 720 --output NameOfDisc_Title$i.mp4; done`

And it seems that it is merging the chapters into one `NameOfDisc_Title$i.mp4` file. But is it?

Comment: Depends on how the disk is laid out.  Most of the TV series discs I have used the first title that deals with the episodes is usually all the episodes of the disc together.  Then the next so many titles is each individual episode.  You might want to load the disc up into HandBrake and make sure the titles are the ones you are trying to get.

Comment: Or you can try installing `lsdvd` that will command line allow you to see all the chapters of a disc.  Just some thoughts for you.

Comment: `lsdvd` gives me two (2) titles, but I know there is four (4) "episodes", strange.